# How can I parse roman numerals in Haskell's Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm a Haskell beginner, and I'm trying to learn about Parsec by writing a parser that can consume either an arabic numeral, like "234," or a roman one, like "MCMLXIX." I found [the library roman-numerals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/roman-numerals-0.5.1.5/docs/Text-Numeral-Roman.html), and so I figured I'd try to use the `fromRoman` function somehow, in conjunction with Parsec, since I'll eventually need to get the arabic equivalent of the roman numeral. But I just don't quite yet know how to coerce the `Maybe` output of `fromRoman` into a `Parser`. This is what I have so far:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Text (Parser)
import Text.Numeral.Roman

arabicNum :: Parser Int
arabicNum = do
  n <- many1 digit
  return (read n)

isChapter :: Inline -> Bool
isChapter str = str == Str "CHAPTER"

number :: Parser Int
number = arabicNum <|> romanNum

romanNum :: Parser Int
romanNum = do
  str <- many1 char
  return case (fromRoman str) of
    Just n -> n
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

But, no dice, since I don't quite yet know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `Maybe` is `Nothing`, you can `fail` to generate a parser error. If it's something, you can `return` it:

```
romanNum :: Parser Int
romanNum = do
  str <- many1 $ oneOf "MDCLXVI"
  case fromRoman str of
    Just n -> return n
    Nothing -> fail $ str ++ " is not a valid roman numeral"
```